# Ansible: homebrew_cask throws "Invalid cask: XXX"

Tags: ansible, homebrew

I'm learning Ansible and I'm trying to convert these Homebrew commands using Ansible's `homebrew_tap` and `homebrew_cask`:

```
brew tap homebrew/cask-fonts
brew install --cask font-hack-nerd-font
```

My Ansible playbook looks like this:

```
---
- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Tapping homebrew/cask-fonts
    homebrew_tap:
      name: homebrew/cask-fonts

  - name: Installing Nerd Font
    homebrew_cask:
      name: font-hack-nerd-font
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
PLAY [test] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Tapping homebrew/cask-fonts] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Installing Nerd Font] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Invalid cask: font-hack-nerd-font."}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I'm hoping to be able to pull this off using `homebrew_cask` without `brew` command directly.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried including [`update_homebrew: yes`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/community/general/homebrew_cask_module.html#parameter-update_homebrew) in your `homebrew_cask:` task? it's possible the CLI does it automatically, but ansible chooses not to in order to not conflate the two actions. Running ansible at higher verbosity may help figure out the difference, too

Comment: Yes, I did and I see the same error. When I use `upgrade_all`, it got past the task but when I run `brew list`, it wasn't installed. It seems like this only happen when the cask is "tapped" from other external repos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [reported as a bug](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/issues/1037) due to hyphen(s) in the cask package name. This bug is resolved via [pull request](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/pull/1038).